# Is using the same VBO for two objects okay?

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, vbo, freeglut

Lets say if I have multiple of the same Object and I want to render them in different places. Could I use the same VBO (to save ram) but change the matrices that are sent to the Shader? Or it this wrong?

Comment: It's the best thing you can do.

Comment: Even better, if you want to render the same geometry in multiple locations within the scene you should look into instanced rendering.  You can fill a buffer object with all the various transformations and reference them in a shader, then draw all the objects with a single call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fine and recommended, most people do this to avoid duplicate data in memory which is of no use. There is no penalty for doing so.